# Copy html elements of a variable <div> along with other elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is a `<div>` which functions as a *markdown to html converter*, the inner `html` of which is variable:

```
<div id="markdown" class="classname">
</div>
```

I want to make a javascript function which copies **(to the clipboard)** the inner `html` of the `<div>`, together with a stylesheet for the `div`: (note: the stylesheet is not variable)

```
<style>
html {
font-size: 13px; 
line-height: 1.5; 
padding:60px;
}
 <!-- and many more... -->
</style>
```

The expected copied result is as follows;

```
<style>
html {
font-size: 13px; 
line-height: 1.5; 
padding:60px;
}
 <!-- and many more... -->
</style>
<!-- below are sample contents from the <div> -->
<h1>markdown test</h1>
<p>hello</p>
```

What script is needed to achieve this? Copying the result through window `prompt` alert is also fine.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AxelMoriceau A javascript which downloads the inner html of the `<div>`(without stylesheet) as an html file is already done, which is not so convenient to use. This is why I'm trying to copy the code instead of downloading it.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  `var style="<style>html { ... }</style>";  return style + $("#markdown").html();`  What do you mean by "copies the html" - do you mean to the clipboard?  Or just into a variable (.html())?  Or to somewhere else on the page (.clone())?  Please clarify.

Comment: @freedomn-m to the clipboard. I should have pointed that out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+copy+to+clipboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @freedomn-m no, let's put it this way; I'm looking for a way to copy the html elements inside a `<div>` to the clipboard, not just the displayed raw texts but the html tags as well. I want this to be done in any way that is possible, such as by clicking a button, or displaying a window prompt alert.

Comment: So... `alert(html);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of jQuery here, use below script where you can read `HTML` of markdown `div` along with css script

```js
$(function(){
  var html = $('#markdown').html();
  console.log(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="markdown" class="classname">
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      padding: 60px;
    }
    
    <!-- and many more... -->
  </style>
  <!-- below are sample contents from the <div> -->
  <h1>markdown test</h1>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

by using `clone()` function of jquery you can copy the html and append it in another element.

Ex. :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="goodbye">
    Goodbye
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>

$( ".hello" ).html();
```